# issue with vtk python wrapping: can't import vtk in interpreter but can import in console

Tags: python, wrapper, pydev, vtk

I compiled vtk with python wrapping and I can us it on the command line. 
However, I am using eclipse IDE and want to use vtk but no matter what I do with my PYTHONPATH variable, I still get the errors below:

```
  from filtering import * 
File "C:\Development\third-party\vtk-5.6.1\build\Wrapping\Python\vtk\filtering.py", line 9, in <module>
  from vtkFilteringPython import * 
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

My PATH and PYTHONPATH contain:

```
"C:\Development\third-party\vtk-5.6.1\Wrapping\Python" 
"C:\Development\third-party\vtk-5.6.1\build\bin\Release" which has the  *.lib, *.pyd, *.dll
```

In the DOS console, that is all I need and I can "import vtk" with no errors.

However, in eclipse I set the "External Libraries" of my project to contain the same directories above and I get an error.

The error happens at  in the file "C:\Development\third-party\vtk-5.6.1\Wrapping\Python\vtk__init__.py" : 
just after loading vtk "common" library.

```
... 
# Load all required kits. 
from common import * 
from filtering import * 
...
```

The funny thing is that both vtkcommon and vtkfiltering python (.dll, .lib and .pyd) are all in the same folder here: "C:\Development\third-party\vtk-5.6.1\build\bin\Release"

Can someone please help ? Why would import vtk work on console and not in  eclipse IDE ?

I am using Version: Juno Service Release 2 
Build id: 20130225-0426 for eclipse, vtk-5.6, python 2.6.5 and pydev 2.7.3

Can anyone with pydev + vtk experience help me?

Comment: any one ? I ran out of ideas ...

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems with VTK on PyDev and I just found [this article](http://www.switchcase.org/), to do with PyCUDA on PyDev. It helped me get things working on Linux.

I followed the instructions there: Go to Run->Run Configurations and add a new environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH

I also found [this forum](http://www.coderanch.com/t/105391/vc/Configuring-eclipse-dll-files-runtime), which deals with a similar problem on Windows. They suggest adding

```
-Djava.library.path="{dll path}"
```

to your runtime args in eclipse. See [this page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) on the eclipse wiki.